# Coordinate free atomic orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors

I asked about coordinate free attacks on the Schrodinger equation and I got this interesting link in response:

[The SO(4) Symmetry of the Hydrogen Atom by Sean J. Weinberg](http://hep.uchicago.edu/%7Erosner/p342/projs/weinberg.pdf)

However, as far as I understand neither the paper nor any related ones actually provide the calculation for the shape of the probability distributions.

The reason I'm interested in this is because I suspected that just a brute force spherical coordinate calculation would obstruct some fundamental intrinsic structure (I didn't know it was the s04 symmetry group ) but I knew that a coordinate free computation based on Laplace vector would have a lot of merit as in classical mechanics one gets the intrinsic eccentricity vector with respect to which the angle of the position can be determined without arbitrary axis.

But ultimately the position equation is basically the same as its spherical coordinate counterpart.

So if one can't solve the equation without coordinates effectively, can the angle parameters be interpreted in some intrinsic coordinate free way, as the angle in the Kepler orbit is the angles WRT a intrinsic eccentricity vector?

Comment: It's not in Bander, M., & Itzykson, C. (1966). Group theory and the hydrogen atom (I), *Reviews of modern Physics* **38** (2), 330. ? In any case, Pauli's matrix approach finds spectra, bypassing messy/uninformative wavefunctions!